# node js and mongodb asynchronous issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

i'm new to mongodb and i'm having problems updating a local variable after a query. i'm using node js and i have a local variable i'm trying to update depending on my query result, but it seems that my functions returns before the query. i understand node js is asynchronous but i'm having trouble dealing with that. you can see my code below:

```js
function userExist(userList, username){
    //var usert = new UserSchema()
    var exist = false
    UserSchema.findOne({userName: username}, function (err, usert) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      if (usert) {
        // doc may be null if no document matched
        exist = true
      }
    })
    console.log("boolean " + bool)
    return exist
   // return username in userList
    // return query
}
```

I'm also having a different but unrelated issue where i'm trying to extract a specific value from a query result. my schema is as follow:

```js
//import dependency
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
//create new instance of the mongoose.schema. the schema takes an
//object that shows the shape of your database entries.
var UserSchema = new Schema({
 userName: String,
 userID: String,
 Conversations: [
   {
     conversationID: String,
     messages: [
       {
         message: String,
         messageID: String,
         sender: String,
         time: String
       }
     ]
   }
 ]
})
//export our module to use in server.js
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

i'm trying to get the values in conversations array, add a new conversation to it and push it back in the database.

An answer to either question would be really helpful and appreciated.

just for clarification this is where i'm using the userExist function:

```js
//Verify Username
 socket.on(VERIFY_USER, (nickname, callback)=>{
  if(userExist(connectedUsers, nickname)){
      console.log("user exist")
   callback({ userExist:true, user:null })
  }else{
      console.log("user does not exist")
   callback({ userExist:false, user:createUser({name:nickname, socketId:socket.id})})
  }
 })
```

Comment: `findOne` is async, so `userExist` should return a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out the findOne returns a promise.

You can handle the promise executing callbacks on the success or fail of the findOne result

Define two functions to pass as callbacks

```
function success(user){
    //no error check 
    //doc has been found
    //do something 
    } ;
function fail(err){
    console. log(err) 
    }
```

Then in the findOne function body

```
if (err) return fail(err) ;
//else
return success(user)
```

OR

you can wrap the userExist function body to return a promise

```
function userExist(userList, username){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var exist = false
    UserSchema.findOne({userName: username}, function (err, usert) {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      if (usert) {
        // doc may be null if no document matched
        exist = true
        resolve(exist)
      }
    })
})   
}
```

And when you call the userExist

```
 userExist(userList, username).then(function(user){
       //do something with the user
    }).catch(function(reason) {
         console.error(reason);
    });
```

Comment: this is not really having the desired effect.  i call the userexist function in an if statement and whenever i call it, it returns after the if statement execute.       if(userexist){do something} else {do something else}

Comment: findOne is async and you must deal with it with promises or callbacks, I have added an alternative , I hope it can help you

Comment: it does help a lot, had to move the resolve out of the if statement everything works now thanks you